# Enter key event handling

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, event-handling

**----- New Jquery for answer  from comment  -----**

```
function search2() {
    var urlString = 'Controls/LookUp.aspx?zipcode=' + $('#MultiSearch2').val();

    window.location = urlString;
    return false;
}

jQuery('#MultiSearch2').bind("keypress", function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        search2();
    }
});
```

Ok, here is how everything is kind of set up.

I have a main.master page that has the following code in it.

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelMainMaster" runat="server" DefaultButton="searchBTN">
    <div id="HomeQuickSearch">
        <input id="multiSearchStyle" type="text" placeholder ="search our store" />
        <asp:Button OnClientClick="return searchZone()" runat="server" Text="Go" ID="searchBTN" />     
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

I have another master page (tree) with the following code in it:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" DefaultButton="submit">
    <form name="ZipCodeForm" action="/Search.cfm" method="get">
        <div style="margin-bottom: .25em">Search for a tree:</div>
        <input type="text" name="MultiSearch" id="MultiSearch" size="15" maxlength="50" style="margin-bottom: .25em">
        <asp:Button Text="Search" runat="server" ID="submit" OnClientClick="return search()" />
    </form>
</asp:Panel>
```

And then, there is a custom content page created through a third party that shows up within the second master page with this code:

```
<div id="TreeStyle">
    <Z:CustomMessage ID="Tree1" MessageKey="TreeHero" runat="server" />
</div>
```

The HTML rendered from the custom message:

```
<input id="MultiSearch2" type="text" name="MultiSearch2" maxlength="50">
<button id="submit2" name="submit2" type="submit">Search</button>
```

The page is rendered in following flow:

1. Main.Master
2. Tree.Master
3. Custom Message within Tree.Master

The first two input textboxes handle the Enter button event click with the `DefaultButton` option on the `asp:Panel`. However, there is a third textbox and search button that is created because of the custom message within the `Tree.Master` and that CANNOT have any `ASP` in it, only `HTML`.

My question is, how can I handle this Enter keypress event and have it search with the value from the third textbox instead of the value from the frist or second.

I have tried this, but it didn't work. Not too much surprise there though.

```
function search2() {
    var urlString = 'Controls/LookUp.aspx?zipcode=' + $('#MultiSearch2').val();

    window.location = urlString;
    return false;
}

jQuery('#MultiSearch2').on("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        search2();
    }
});
```

I am also getting a jquery error I wasn't noticing before: `object [object Object] has no method 'on'`

Comment: Try using the [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method inside `keypress`.

Comment: Cool, that worked @PalashMondal. If you make an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Brett It seems you got it resolved using Palash's help. Please answer your own question so that it will help future posters.

Comment: @JayPatel just did, added it to the bottom of the question.

Comment: @Brett But it is still part of the question. Post it as an answer otherwise it will be hard to find as it is at the end of your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
jQuery('#MultiSearch2').on("keypress", function (e) {            

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {

        // Cancel the default action on keypress event
        e.preventDefault(); 

        search2();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**----- New Jquery for answer  from comment  -----**

```
function search2() {
    var urlString = 'Controls/LookUp.aspx?zipcode=' + $('#MultiSearch2').val();

    window.location = urlString;
    return false;
}

jQuery('#MultiSearch2').bind("keypress", function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        search2();
    }
});
```